# Controlling "srt" in text() to work selectively in R

Tags: r, if-statement, plot

I have a word plotted on a curve line (**as shown blow**). I was wondering how I could have `srt` within the `text()` to operate conditionally this way:

***srt = for the plotted words whose x values are SMALLER than "-2" srt = -45, LARGER than "+2", srt = "45", else srt = "0"?***

**My R code is below the picture.**

[image]

**Here is my R code:**

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, bty = 'n', yaxt = 'n') 

x.on.curve = seq(-4, 4, len = 21)
y.on.curve = dnorm(x.on.curve)

text(x.on.curve, y.on.curve, "Data", col = 'green', font = 2, pos = 3, xpd = T)
    ## This is where I want "srt" to work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That choice of angle would not be mine, but you can adjust as you see fit.

Each `text` can only use one `srt`, but you can use more than one `text` command.

```
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, bty = 'n', yaxt = 'n') 
x.on.curve = seq(-4, 4, len = 21)
y.on.curve = dnorm(x.on.curve)

text(x.on.curve[x.on.curve < -2], y.on.curve[x.on.curve < -2], 
    "Data", col = 'green', font = 2, pos = 3, xpd = T, srt=-45) 
text(x.on.curve[x.on.curve > 2], y.on.curve[x.on.curve > 2], 
    "Data", col = 'green', font = 2, pos = 3, xpd = T, srt=45) 
text(x.on.curve[x.on.curve >= -2 & x.on.curve <= 2], 
    y.on.curve[x.on.curve >= -2 & x.on.curve <= 2], 
    "Data", col = 'green', font = 2, pos = 3, xpd = T, srt=0)
```

[image: Slanted text]